# 'http' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ngrok

For running ngrok from command prompt I used the command (http ngrok portnumber) from the path where my python.exe file and ngrok file is stored(both are stored at same location). I'm getting error that "'http' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
while installing http, using pip install http. I'm getting another error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output." Please help.

Comment: You have reported that you entered some commands and got some error messages.  It would be helpful if you explained what you are trying to accomplish and why you thought those commands should work.

Comment: Hi @DennisSparrow I'm working on google dialogflow, for that I need to run ngrok and then it will generate a link which I need to pass in fullfilment text of dialogflow. but I'm not able to run ngrok because for running ngrok I need to run command (http ngrok portnumber) but i'm getting error http is not recogized.

Comment: Try `ngrok http <yourportnumber>`

Comment: Hey @JintoLonappan, this worked. Thanks Man.